# 書籍「実装で学ぶフルスタックweb開発」でbackendとのaxios接続で躓いてます

Tags: docker, django, next.js, webapi, axios

この本はWindowsを対象に書かれているのですが、今回Macで同じことを学んでいます。

Dockerでfrontend, backend, MySQLのコンテナを用意し、以下のようにAPIを取得するという流れですが、ネットワークエラーが起きうまくいきません。

`localhost:3000` から `localhost:8000` という感じかと思ってるんですがDockerが受け付けないなど考えられるのでしょうか？

```
'use client'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Page() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ message: '' })

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('/api/hello_db/backend')
            .then((res) => res.data)
            .then((data) => {
                setData(data)
            })
    }, [])
    return <div>hello {data.message}!</div>
```

Comment: 質問が修正されていますが、アクセスするURLが間違っていて、localhost3000の様に、localhost:3000と、`:`が抜けていてアクセス出来ないという可能性は無いですか？

Comment: 「ネットワークエラー」って何ですか？　ブラウザの開発者ツールなどを使って要求・応答をキャプチャして、要求が期待通り出ているか、応答が期待通り返ってきているか調べることはできませんか？

Answer (score 0):

CORS エラーということでdjango-cors-headersをpipしてセッテイングに追記することで解決できました！

```
pip install django-cors-headers==3.7.0
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

Comment: 私も質問者様と同じ事象が発生し詰まっています。 pip install django-cors-headers==3.7.0 requirement.lockファイルに追加したという認識でよいでしょうか。
現在出版社に問い合わせしておりますが、もし可能でしたらご返信いただければ幸いです。

Comment: ターミナルやコマンドプロンプトで
``>pip install django-cors-headers==3.7.0``
と実行したってことだと思いますよ？

Comment: tkn さんの問題はバックエンドが CORS に対応してないことによるのですか？

Comment: @tkn さん
私もこちらの部分で苦戦しました。。

 コマンドでpip install django-cors-headers==3.7.0 
を実行しインストールしました。
また、requirements.txtにdjango-cors-headers==3.7.0と書き込みrequirement.lockもしました。
あと、base.pyのINSTALLED_APPS = ['corsheaders',], 
 MIDDLEWARE = ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',], 
 CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:3000”,],
と書き加えて解決しました。

もしかすると別の方法でbase.pyに
CROSS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CROSS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
としてもよいのかもしれません。

またなにかあれば聞いてください。頑張ってください